# Pillow Image.convert multiframe tiff mode 1 to 'RGB' - not saving all frames

Tags: python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a multiframe tiff image with mode 1 that I want to convert to a multiframe tiff with mode 'RGB'. It is only saving a single frame in the output. Am I missing something?

```
def q(file_path='test.tiff'):
  with Image.open(file_path) as image:
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
      n = image.convert('RGB')
      n.save(fp='new.tiff', format="TIFF", save_all=True, compression="None")
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the sequence of frames. See [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#reading-sequences).

Code attributable to above link:

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("animation.gif") as im:
   im.seek(1)  # skip to the second frame

   try:
      while 1:
         im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
         # do something to im
   except EOFError:
      pass  # end of sequence
```